# bluetooth headset with LCD and memory

Tags: led, bluetooth, lcd, telephone

I was wondering if it is possible to create a bluetooth device which would have a LCD screen and some memory (1kb) for making and receiving calls.

From my research ( and I am far from an EE, but trying to learn as I go) i found that arduino doesnt support HFP or HSP.  What Id like the device do is, go through a small list of numbers on lcd, choose one and make a call through the bluetooth connection to a smartphone.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT. so while looking online a found a BT module RN-52, has both SSP and HFP/HSP, and when looking at the PDF for the RN-52 Evaluation kit i found on page 24 that it has a command to call any phone number that it is given.
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/rn-bt-audio-ug-2.0r.pdf

My question now is. Can it be connected to an arduino uno, so that it can send a number to the rn-52, so it can call it?

thanks

Comment: Check the M24SR-DISCOVERY from ST. It has a display, bluetooth and several other "goodies".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll have any problems connecting it to the arduino.  As an example, you can look at the Sparkfun RN-52 breakout. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11777  Even if it doesn't work out for you, you can look at their schematic and eagle files which might help you as well as the hookup guide.